# Cant select option from dropdown which is inside iframe - selenium - java8

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I am trying to select option from the drop down in iframe but it is not getting selected.

```
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.get("https://verify-taxcerts.floridarevenue.com");
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.id("ivuFrm_page0ivu3")));
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.findElement(By.id("OFFM.SellerVerView.TaxTypeDDKey")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id("OFFM.SellerVerView.TaxTypeDDKey")).sendKeys("Sales and Use Tax");
```

Error

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: #OFFM\.SellerVerView\.TaxTypeDDKey
```

Use case : i am trying to select option "sales and Use Tax"

what i am doing wrong ?

selenium version :3.14

ff : 70

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's one more frame with `isolatedWorkArea` id:

```
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.id("ivuFrm_page0ivu3")));
// one more iframe
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.id("isolatedWorkArea")));
driver.findElement(By.id("OFFM.SellerVerView.TaxTypeDDKey")).click();
```

Comment: how do i find index of those frame ids i am trying to do same thing in selenium ide also but not sure how to calculate index number of iframe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58650887/new-selenium-ide-switch-to-iframe-using-frame-id

Comment: I use chrome devtools. Open and inspect and search in HTML.