# New Selenium IDE switch to iframe using frame id

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I am trying to select an element which is inside Iframe in selenium ide but selenium IDE not able to identify element.

```
open | https://verify-taxcerts.floridarevenue.com
pause | | 30000
select frame | id=ivuFrm_page0ivu3
select frame | id=isolatedWorkArea
click | OFFM.SellerVerView.TaxTypeDDKey
type | somename
```

This is how i am doing it in java not sure how to do it in selenium ide.Below code is working fine

```
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.get("https://verify-taxcerts.floridarevenue.com");
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.id("ivuFrm_page0ivu3")));
    // one more iframe
    driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.id("isolatedWorkArea")));
    driver.findElement(By.id("OFFM.SellerVerView.TaxTypeDDKey")).click();
```

Incase if i want to use index=x in selenium ide how do i find exact iframe index of ivuFrm_page0ivu3 and isolatedWorkArea .

What is right way to select iframe using frame id in selenium ide

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`selectFrame` doesn't have an `id` option, you can only use `index` or `relative`, [from the documentation](https://ui.vision/rpa/docs/selenium-ide/selectframe).